# PHP Load image into array, 2 bit

Tags: php

I want to load an entire image (PNG) into a 2-dimensional array where a black pixel is `true` and a white pixel is `false`.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Should I convert the image into bitmap and attempt to read that in, or is there a more efficient method?

Comment: And what if its not black or white?

Comment: It is always black or white, it's a 2bit bitmap.

Comment: Note: A black&white bitmap is *1-bit*, because you only need 1 bit of information (black or white) for each pixel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("input.png");
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$colors = array();

for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
{
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

        $black = ($r == 0 && $g == 0 && $b == 0);
        $colors[$x][$y] = $black;
    } 
}
```

A probably more efficient way would be using [`Imagick::exportImagePixels()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.exportimagepixels.php).

Comment: I know about `imagecolorat()`, and I'm looking for something more efficient. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Alasdair you didn't mention that in your question. If you have ImageMagick, you can take a look at [`exportImagePixels()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.exportimagepixels.php) and loop through that array.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained in more detail. The whole reason I want to do this is to bypass GD.

Comment: @Alasdair how much of GD do you want to bypass? You want to decode PNG in pure PHP? You want an offline task outside PHP?

Comment: I was planning to convert the PNG to bitmap and read this into an array, completely bypassing GD. But I've given up now. This answer here is technically correct, and I didn't phrase my question very well, so I will accept.